# AEM - How to tweak activation error message

Tags: aem

We are working in an AEM 6.1 environment and have created an activation preprocessor that will stop pages from being activated if certain attributes are not set. That works great but we'd also like to change the error message that's displayed by the activation process when the preprocessor throws a ReplicationExcdeption. Can anyone point me to the code that actually displays the error message?

Comment: could you please add more details, what you did

Comment: I created a class that implements the com.day.cq.replication.Preprocessor interface. It's called by AEM as part of the activation process and throws a RepositoryException if it doesn't find particular attributes. This stops the activation and displays a message to the user but I'd like to change the message that's displayed and I don't know where it's actually generated.

Answer (score 0):

We overrided several functions in SiteAdmin.Actions.js. Copy it from libs folder `/apps/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/wcm/SiteAdmin.Actions.js` or use [CQ.Ext.override](https://edspencer.net/2009/07/24/extoverride-monkey-patching-ext-js/)

We need to override `CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.scheduleForActivation` and `CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.internalActivatePage`  methods.

We do it with using the following code

```
CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.internalActivatePage = function(paths, callback) {
    if (callback == undefined) {
        // assume scope is admin and reload grid
        var admin = this;
        callback = function(options, success, response) {
            if (success) admin.reloadPages();
            else admin.unmask();
        };
    }

    preActionCallback = function(options, success, response) {
        if (success) {
            var responseObj = CQ.Util.eval(response);
            if (responseObj.activation) {
                CQ.HTTP.post(
                    CQ.shared.HTTP.externalize("/bin/replicate.json"),
                    callback,
                    { "_charset_":"utf-8", "path":paths, "cmd":"Activate" }
                    );
            } else {
                CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.preactivateMessage(responseObj);
            }
        }else{
            CQ.Ext.Msg.alert(
                    CQ.I18n.getMessage("Error"), CQ.I18n.getMessage("Could not activate page."));
        }
        admin.unmask();
    };

    CQ.HTTP.get(
            "/apps/sling/servlet/content/preActivateValidator.html?path=" + paths,
            preActionCallback
    );
};
```

This path `/apps/sling/servlet/content/preActivateValidator.html` (You can use any other link and extension) returns json with some info about messages, which are parsed in custom method and generates custom error messages `CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.preactivateMessage`:

```
CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.preactivateMessage = function(responseObj) {
    var message = "";
    var incorrectItems = responseObj.incorrectItems;
    if (responseObj.countOfIncorrectItems > 1) message = message + "s";
    if (responseObj.missingMetadata) {
        message = message + "Please, set \"Programming Type\" for next videos:<br/>";
        var missingMetadataPaths = responseObj.missingMetadata;
        for(var i = 0; i < missingMetadataPaths.length; i++){
            message = message + "<a href=\""+missingMetadataPaths[i].path+".html\">"+missingMetadataPaths[i].path+"</a><br/>";
        }
        message += "<br/>";
    }
    if(message == ""){
        message = "Unknown error.";
    }
    CQ.Ext.Msg.alert(
        CQ.I18n.getMessage("Error"), CQ.I18n.getMessage(message));
}
```

So you can implement component or servlet which will verify your attributes and will generate JSON.

Comment: I'll have a look at this. Thanks for the response!